# MYSQL insert next weeks dates if not in database

Tags: mysql, sql, dateadd

I am wondering this DATE_ADD function while handy, I seem to not understand its feature, as I am trying to get it to insert all the dates for the week ahead. As the business owner only wants that weeks dates to be active on the site.

tried:

```
insert into booking ('appiontmentdate') values (DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

Comment: `VALUES (curdate()), (date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day)), (date_add(curdate(), interval 2 day)), ...`

Comment: Did it sit in the living room and only played video games? What do you mean by 'not work'?

Comment: lol @Ja͢ck no, it sad this error Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)' at line 1

Comment: Getting the syntax of a SQL statement right only requires reading the documentation, so I hope you don't mind me refraining from doing that ;)

Comment: I checked that and http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/ said the code was fine

Comment: This sounds like a job for the code not a DB.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a ')' at the end of your original SQL, Russell.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an extra ')' at the end of your original SQL statement:

```
insert into booking ('appiontmentdate') values (DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK));
```

HTH